# NodeJs with Mongoose - Nested queries async issue

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, nested, subquery

I have to mongodb collections, like this:

```
UserGroup collection
    fields: 
        name: String
        group_id: Number
User collection
    fields:
        user_name: String
        group_id: Number
```

I want generate a report like this:

```
ADMINISTRATORS
--------------------------
jlopez
rdiaz

OPERATORS
--------------------------
amiralles
dcamponits
```

But I get the following report:

```
ADMINISTRATORS
--------------------------
OPERATORS
--------------------------
jlopez
rdiaz
amiralles
dcamponits
```

Following is the code to generate the report:

```
UserGroup.find({}, (err, groups) => {
    for(var i in groups){   
        console.log(groups[i].name)
        console.log("--------------------")
        User.find( {group_id : groups[i].group_id}, (err, users) =>{
            for(var j in users){
                console.log(users[j].user_name)
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Clearly, this is a problem of the NodeJs/Mongoose asynchronicity.

**QUESTION:** How do I make the first For cycle wait until the internal cycle ends for each UserGrop?

Thanks in advance,

David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run an aggregation pipeline that uses **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** to do a "left-join" to another collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing. With this you won't need any async library:

```
UserGroup.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "group_id",
            "foreignField": "group_id",
            "as": "users"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": 1,
            "users": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$users",
                    "as": "user",
                    "in": "$$user.user_name"
                }
            }
        }
    }
], (err, groups) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(groups, null, 4));
})
```

**Sample Output**

```
[
    {
        "name": "ADMINISTRATORS",
        "users": ["jlopez", "rdiaz"]
    },
    {
        "name": "OPERATORS",
        "users": ["amiralles", "dcamponits"]
    }
]
```

Comment: This works very well and as you mention, it is not necessary to use another library. ¡Thank you very much chridam!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for [asyc](https://github.com/caolan/async), you can get a get basic idea from following code. it is based on async each & waterfall. [ Please add proper error handling for the following code yourself.]

```
UserGroup.find({}, (err, groups) => {
  async.each(groups, (group, callback) =>{
    async.waterfall([
      (wCallback) => {
        User.find({group_id : group.group_id}, wCallback)
      },
      (users, wCallback) => {
        console.log(group.name)
        console.log("--------------------")
        for(var j in users){
          console.log(users[j].user_name)
        }
        wCallback()
      }
    ], callback)
})
})
```

Comment: I was perfect Ratan Kumar. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Ratan. I'm new to Stackoverflow.
In the first place I was surprised how quickly people respond.
While I said your answer solves the problem, I think the use of `Aggregation Pipeline` mentioned by the user _chridam_ is the best solution because it is not necessary to use external libraries. **Anyway thank you very much!**

Answer (score 0):

Add support for promises to mongoose.  I use q, but you can use bluebird too.

```
mongoose.Promise = require('q').Promise;
```

Then you can use q.all to resolve once all of the user queries have completed.

```
var promises = []; 
var groups = [];
UserGroup.find({}, (err, groups) => {
    for(var i in groups){
        groups.push(groups[i]);
        promises.push(User.find( {group_id : groups[i].group_id}));
    }
});

q.all(promises).then( function(usersByGroup){
    var indx = 0;
    usersByGroup.forEach(function(users){

    var grp = groups[indx];
    console.log(groups[i].name);
    console.log("--------------------");
    for(var j in users){
        console.log(users[j].user_name)
    }
    indx++;
    });
});
```